# Create contact by external form fails (using contact form in wordpress with plugins, civi runs on drupal)

Tags: contacts, forms

I've followed [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external) to create a setup for my visitors to subscribe from a wordpress website to a newsletter in CiviCRM. CiviCRM setup is working (I have tested via API Explorer, it works as expected). I have installed Contact Form 7 and it's civicrm supporting plugins to a Wordpress (as described in the post).

I've set the plugin with keys (API and Site) that I've tested. I created a form, filled it and it sent a request to my site and returned a 403 error:
"POST /civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?json=1&entity=FormProcessor&action=create_subscriber HTTP/1.1" 403

The keys are working but I can't check if they're sent correctly. To see what is being sent in the POST request, I've looked to my browser console, but there was no POST request to my civi installation.

I ran out of ideas to check. What can I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the extension for remote forms?
I use it and it has a very nice and clean look (you can customize the css as well if you'd like) 
It's not like cf so you can't add random fields but for a basic profile it would work great. https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's not for me I guess. It's highly fragile as external javascripts are widely blocked by plugins. Also one of the websites I have to collect data from is not forcing https (which is required by the remoteform). I know I have to fix that anyway, but I'm not in charge of that server, so I'm waiting it to be fixed.

But, I have to add, if my scenario is a mixed system with wordpress+drupal on the same domain, I think this is a good solution.